# How to use vi.spyOn on a function with the vue 3 composition API

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

I'm using TypeScript and the vue 3 composition API.

I've got a function in an component (in uploadFile.vue) that I want to (unit)test using Vitest:

```
<template>
    <div style="display: none">
      <input
        ref="input"
        type="file"
        @change="addNewImage($event)"
      />
    </div>
</template>


const addNewImage = async (event: Event): Promise<void> => {
...
}
```

In my uploadFile.spec.ts I do:

```
import { afterEach, describe, it, expect, vi, beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { mount, shallowMount, VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
import UploadFile from './UploadFile.vue'

describe('UploadFile', () => {

  it('renders the component', () => {
    const addImageSpy = vi.spyOn(UploadFile, 'addNewImage')
    const wrapper = shallowMount(UploadFile, {
      ...
    }
    const input = wrapper.find('input[type="file"]');
    await input.trigger('change')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(addImageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

However, my terminal shows the error: 'addNewImage does not exist' (while pointing at vi.spyOn(fileUpload, 'addImage').

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The component definition doesn't have an `addImageSpy` member. `wrapper.vm` does:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(UploadFile, {
  //...
}
const addImageSpy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'addNewImage')
//...
```